# Angular click event not fired when custom input is focused

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I created simple custom input `eu-input` element using 'ControlValueAccessor'. Now I have something like that:

```
  <eu-input></eu-input>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="choose(item)">
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
  </div>
```

But there is problem I can't figure out. When `eu-input` is focused, click event doesn't get fired, it's fired only after `eu-input` is blured (on second attempt).
so what could be a problem?

this is html:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value"/>local: {{val}}
```

and this is ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'eu-input',
  templateUrl: './eu-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./eu-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => EuInputComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class EuInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}
  onChange: any = () => {};
  onTouch: any = () => {};
  val = '';
  set value(val) {
    if (val !== undefined && this.val !== val) {
      this.val = val;
      this.onChange(val);
      this.onTouch(val);
    }
  }
  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }
}
```

choose() method is just console.log('choose clicked')

Comment: I dont understand - which click event are you talking about? We have here click event on the div but not on `eu-input`.

Comment: can you share your code? html and ts?

Comment: Right, I mean click event on div.

Comment: The two things (eu-input and the other divs) have nothing to do with each other. It's hard to understand, why a normal (click) event on a div  no longer works. Please show us the choose() method. Better: make a stackblitz please.

Comment: I see, but I should click div twice if input is focused, first click makes it blur, second triggers actual click event function `choose`

Comment: the thing is also that if I won't use ngFor, than everything works fine

Comment: As mentioned, you would have to add more information such as your `choose()` method in the `typescript` file

Comment: choose() method is just console.log('choose clicked')

Comment: I added eu-input, it's just simple custom input element

Answer (score -1):

**Change eu-input component html to**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value" (focus)="emitFocused(true)" (blur)="emitFocused(false)"/>local: {{val}}
```

**In eu-input TypeScript**

```
@Output() focus = new EventEmitter();
public emitFocused(value) {
   this.focus.emit(value);
}
```

**Can be used like**

```
<eu-input (focus)="myMethod($event)"></eu-input>
```